# yarn dev This dependency was not found:

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, yarnpkg, babel-loader

I have a VueJS project. I run on my MacBook (Mojave 10.14.6, node 8.9.4, npm 5.6.0) without any problem (npm install && yarn dev). But there is a problem when running on Ubuntu 18.04 (node 8.9.4, npm 5.6.0)

```
yarn run v1.17.3
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=development node build/dev-server.js

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                               06:57:46

This dependency was not found:

* !!babel-loader!./Payment.js in ./src/component/PayMent/PayMent.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save !!babel-loader!./Payment.js
> Listening at http://localhost:8686
```

I have tried

```
npm install
npm install babel-loader
```

But the problem isn't resolved

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "async": "^2.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.0.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
```

package-lock.json

```
 "babel-loader": {
      "version": "7.1.2"
```

Comment: Looks like a capitalization problem.

Comment: Check whether the file name is `Payment.js` or `PayMent.js`. Make sure everything matches.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much, DaveNewton, skirtle. But I don't know why it works on Mac OS.